# React error boundary does not catch if error is thrown conditionally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-error-boundary

Can someone explain the following weird error catching behavior by React's error boundaries (see code comments)?

```js
import { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Weird: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [version, setVersion] = useState<number>(0);
    const renderCount = useRef<number>(0);
    const condition = useRef<number>(0);

    console.info(`renderCount=${renderCount.current++}, version=${version}, condition=${condition.current}`);

    useEffect(() => {
        const id: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout(() => setVersion(i => i + 1), 1_000);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }, []);

    // How to test this example:
    // 1. run the code and observe that it works as expected: the error boundary catches the exception
    // 2. change 'errorBoundaryCatchesError' to 'false'
    // 3. comment throwing line marked with "scenario a" below
    // 4. uncomment the throwing line marked with "scenario b" below
    // 5. run the code again to observe that the exception does not get caught by the error boundary anymore
    const errorBoundaryCatchesError: boolean = true;

    if (version === 1) {
        const testCondition: number = errorBoundaryCatchesError ? 1 : 0;
        if (condition.current++ === testCondition) {
            // scenario b - true branch
            // throw new Error("ignored error");
        } else {
            // scenario a - false branch
            throw new Error("caught error");
        }
    }

    return <div>Hello</div>;
}

export default Weird;
```

In other words, if an error is thrown conditionally in the `true` branch of a the timeout-triggered render, it does not get caught, but if it is on the `false` branch, it works as expected...

The above component is wrapped into an error boundary in its parent component as follows:

```js
<ErrorBoundary>
   <Weird />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The error boundary itself is a standard implementation as per [Catching rendering errors with an error boundary](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary)

Comment: For anyone interested, I filed a bug report for this on the official GitHub repo: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/28529